# ar_track_alvar not compiling in Groovy

Tags: ros, ar-track-alvar

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Has anyone been able to make ar_track_alvar work under ROS Groovy? It's working fine for me in Fuerte, but now I'm seeing the following compilation errors because it can't seem to find btMatrix3x3.h

```
In file included from ~/ar_track_alvar/include/Marker.h:42:0,
                 from ~/ar_track_alvar/include/MarkerDetector.h:38,
                 from ~/ar_track_alvar/include/MultiMarker.h:35,
                 from ~/ar_track_alvar/include/MultiMarkerBundle.h:34,
                 from ~/ar_track_alvar/src/MultiMarkerBundle.cpp:24:
~/ar_track_alvar/include/ar_track_alvar/kinect_filtering.h:60:36: fatal error: LinearMath/btMatrix3x3.h: No such file or directory
```

I downloaded the ar_track_alvar code from the git repository on bitbucket.

Then I modified the CMakeLists.txt file to have the eigen workaround mentioned on another forum posting.

**Is there another change required to the ar_track_alvar CMakeLists.txt file to help it locate the btMatrix3x3.h file?**

I know the file exists in the following two locations on my machine:

```
/opt/ros/groovy/stacks/geometry_experimental/tf2/include/LinearMath/btMatrix3x3.h
/opt/ros/groovy/stacks/bullet/include/LinearMath/btMatrix3x3.h
```

Btw, I'm using Ubuntu 12.04 32-bit, and I'm attempting to build it using rosmake:

```
roscd ar_track_alvar
rosmake ar_track_alvar
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/56492/ar_track_alvar-not-compiling-in-groovy/) by [LevelUp](https://answers.ros.org/users/4312/levelup/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2013-02-27

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

We've switched groovy development to Github, but haven't updated the doc page, sorry.  Check out the latest version and switch to the groovy-devel branch (although I'm pretty sure that is the default branch right now):

git clone https://github.com/sniekum/ar_track_alvar.git
git checkout groovy-devel

---

Originally posted by [sniekum](https://answers.ros.org/users/3678/sniekum/) with karma: 101 on 2013-03-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [LevelUp](https://answers.ros.org/users/4312/levelup/) on 2013-03-08**:
The github repo works! Thanks!